# Static Table and deprecated code

Tags: xcode, static, uitableview, deprecated

Ok so i got several static tables i have built, there is a total of 39 lines and all of them have this warning sign

> text is deprecated: first deprecation 3.0

I cant use textLabel b/c it is used for UILabel and then throws a stop up and wont go any further

Any help would be great, Thanks

```
self.noRoomsCool.text = @"No, some rooms are either too hot or too cold when my system runs.";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont get it.. .text is equal to .textLabel.text

please do use the Label and set ITS text property

Comment: Thanks, never thought bout going ahead and put textLabel.text on it. Once i did that all my warnings went away and the app still works.